# SQL Dynamic Pivoting with Dynamic Data

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I am using an SQL Server database and have these following tables

Table "Data"

```
   ------------------
   | Id | data_name |
   ------------------
   | 1  |Data 1     |
   | 2  |Data 2     |
   | 3  |Data 3     |
   | 4  |Data 4     |
   | 5  |Data 5     |
   ------------------
```

and Table "Value_data"

```
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | Id | data_id   | date       | col_1_type | col_1_name | col_1_value | col_2_type | col_2_name | col_2_value |
   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   | 1  | 1         | 2017-01-01 | A          | Alpha      | 12          | B          | Beta       | 23          |
   | 2  | 1         | 2017-02-01 | A          | Alpha      | 32          | B          | Beta       | 42          |
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And i want to make result like so

```
   -----------------------------------------------------------------
   |value_id | data_id | data_name | date       | A-Alpha | B-Beta |
   -----------------------------------------------------------------
   |1        | 1       | Data 1    | 2017-01-01 | 12      | 23     |
   |2        | 1       | Data 1    | 2017-02-01 | 32      | 42     |
   -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've search multiple times for solutions, i've tried using Pivot for example for a static result,

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE ( Id INT, data_name VARCHAR(10) )
INSERT INTO @Data VALUES
( 1 ,'Data 1'),
( 2 ,'Data 2'),
( 3 ,'Data 3'),
( 4 ,'Data 4'),
( 5 ,'Data 5')

DECLARE @Value_data TABLE (Id INT, data_id INT, [date] DATE, col_1_type VARCHAR(10), col_1_name VARCHAR(10), col_1_value INT, col_2_type VARCHAR(10), col_2_name VARCHAR(10), col_2_value INT)
INSERT INTO @Value_data VALUES
( 1, 1, '2017-01-01','A','Alpha','12','B','Beta','23'),
( 2, 1, '2017-02-01','A','Alpha','32','B','Beta','42')

;WITH CTE AS (
    select vd.Id value_id
        , vd.data_id 
        , d.data_name 
        , vd.[date]
        , vd.col_1_type + '-' +vd.col_1_name Col1
        , vd.col_1_value
        , vd.col_2_type + '-' +vd.col_2_name Col2
        , vd.col_2_value
    from @Value_data vd
        inner join @Data d on vd.data_id = d.Id
)   
SELECT * FROM CTE 
    PIVOT( MAX(col_1_value) FOR Col1 IN ([A-Alpha])) PVT_A
    PIVOT( MAX(col_2_value) FOR Col2 IN ([B-Beta])) PVT_B
```

but it wont work well with the data that i'm using with the joining tables because my database will be dynamic, anyone had a solution with the same case?

Comment: You can provide more complicated data pls? Cause as above sample data, I don't think you need to use pivot :))

Comment: oh, i know that it doesnt need to use pivot if it's static, what i meant is that col_1_name is not always going to be Alpha, and col_2_name is not always going to be Beta, It's Dynamic

Comment: If you can build dynamic pivot query ( please refer to http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/t-sql-dynamic-pivot-table-example-code.aspx ) it might help. I am not sure how to apply dynamic query to your requirement, may be you can provide more sample data